# Handle multiple submit buttons in Drupal form API

Tags: drupal

I have 2 submit buttons and want to perform different actions for each submit button . Here I want to set the form fields which can be done only in form_alter(). Can anyone suggest how to check for multiple submit buttons in the form_alter() function?

I have used

```
function myform_form_submit($formID, &$form_state) {
if($form_state['clicked_button']['#value'] == $form_state['values']['submit_one'])    //if button 1      is clicked
     $form_state['redirect'] = 'mypath/page_one';   //redirect to whatever page you want
 else if($form_state['clicked_button']['#value'] == $form_state['values']['submit_two'])  /if button      2 is clicked
    $form_state['redirect'] = 'mypath/page_two';
 }
```

but this does not work

Comment: Do you have a submit hook in your form? $form['#submit'][] = 'myform_form_submit'; ?

Comment: yes, but isn't drupal supposed to pick up the submit function even without the above hook?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The best thing to do if you have two submit buttons on a form and want them to do different things, is to create a different submit function for each button, and connect them up.  One of the nice things about the FormAPI is that it automatically links the form with the submit handler for you, but if you have two submit buttons you want to go somewhere new.

So your form code is likely to contain:

```
$form['submit_one'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Submit One'),
  '#submit' => array('my_module_form_submit_one'),
);
$form['submit_two'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Submit Two'),
  '#submit' => array('my_module_form_submit_two'),
);
```

But I don't know what you mean by form_alter() - there's no reason to use a form alter of any sort.

Edit: As came up in the comments - if you need different validation functions for the two buttons, you can also include `'#validate' => array('my module_form_validate_one')` and `'#validate' => array('my module_form_validate_two')` in the respective button arrays.  But it's not required, and if the standard form validation function works fine then go with that.

Comment: Using two different submit functions sounds like a pretty good solution, but what happens with the validate function? Do you end up with two of those too?

Comment: To answer my own question, the validation function is called for both submit buttons, no need to duplicate it (although it may be possible to have two different validation functions if needed, I do not know)

Comment: And what if you need different validation buttons for the two submit buttons? Let's say we want to add a cancel button on a form where some fields are required. Clicking cancel will throw an error because the same validation function is used to check whether a required field was left empty.

Comment: As asked, you will probably also need to add - '#validate' => array('my_module_form_validate_one'),

Comment: If your second submit button just does some extra processing (either before or after the processing done in the main submit function), you could simply prepend or append an additional submit function to the submit array of the second button, instead of duplicating your common code.  E.g.. $form['submit_two']['#submit'] = array_merge($form['submit_one']['#submit'], array('extra submit function'))

Answer (score 16):

If you want to handle different submit button-click within one submit function, you may check:

```
if($form_state['values']['op'] == BUTTON_ONE_VALUE){
} else if($form_state['values']['op'] == BUTTON_TWO_VALUE){
}
```

Or you may assign certain property to the button first, then check:

```
$form_state['triggering_element']['#attributes'][YOUR_PROPERTY] == VALUE
```

I'm using Drupal 7... Hope this helps

Comment: This is no good though... what if the string changes? WHat if it's in a different language?

Comment: @pandaPowder The string change doesn't matter as long as you have `YOUR_PROPERTY` set

Comment: Multiple submit buttons have #name as 'op'. You will have to override it manually and set a unique value to each button to get $form_state['triggering_element'] working properly

Answer (score 4):

While the accepted answer is correct, it should be noted that you must pass different values with each of your submit buttons, or the submit function used will be the last submit button defined.

In other words, if the value of both submit buttons is 'Submit,' then only the second submit function will be called, regardless of which button is pressed.